# Is every Arduino comes with onboard compass?

Tags: arduino-uno

The doubt was came in mind after seeing Arduino [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/RobotTurn). I have to turn my Arduino uno robot 20 degrees without using encoders. So I surfed on Internet for how can I do that. Interestingly I found the reference available on above link. They are not saying about any specific Arduino board. So I have to know that can I do this stuff on my Arduino uno? Also I have to know is that every Arduino comes with onboard compass?

Comment: No, there is no built-in compass on an arduino microcontroller.  However, you can interface the arduino with a magnetometer sensor to measure the direction of the earth's magnetic field, and use that as a compass.

Comment: If you simply want to obtain a controlled rotation then use a stepper motor.

Comment: the documentation is for this hardware https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-robot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No current Arduino board comes with an on-board compass. That function description comes from the documentation for the [Arduino Robot](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Robot), which is a retired product.

There may be other "maker" dev boards, such as the [Adafruit Circuit Playground Express](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuit-playground-express-compass/overview) which have on-board compass peripherals.